# Set an Element id to a variable - JavaScript / HTML

Tags: javascript, html, var

I was wondering if it was possible to add an id to a variable in JavaScript.

Like This...

**JavaScript:**

```
var name = "#userid";
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="userid" />
```

... So I want to set a variable to the input in the HTML. I have tried using

```
getElementById()
```

I'd like it so when a "userid" is entered into the input, I would like to set that to a variable in JS.

Much Appreciated...

Thank You, James Noon

Comment: What do you mean by "*So I want to set a variable to the input in the HTML.*"?

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling to understand your question.  What exactly to you mean by "add an id to a variable"?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: -- When a "userid" is entered into the input, I would like to set that to a variable in JS... I apologise if I didn't explain it properly

Comment: Ah, so you're wanting to *update* a variable based on the value entered by the user in the HTML input control?

Comment: yes thats exactly what I want.

Comment: is there a submit button to run your JS, or it will run on each keypress?

Comment: Not directly... But some frameworks enable this type of coding (2 way binding). My favorite is http://angularjs.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will update a global variable called `name`, when the value in the textbox is changed (but only once the user has left the control, by clicking or tabbing out)...

```
<input type="text" id="userid" onchange="name=this.value;" />
```

If you want to update the global variable at some other time (a different event) then you want this script...

```
var name = document.getElementById("userid").value;
```

Comment: I don't quite understand... So the onchange="name=this.value;" does that set the value name? because I haven't set var name... I tried it out and its not working

Comment: `name` would have to be a global variable (i.e. not inside a function).  I have also given you the way to get the value directly in the code

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" onChange="setValue(this.value)">


function setValue(value){

var textVal=value;//here u will get the entered text

}
```

Comment: please don't only include code. Also add some text description or it will get flagged.